# Cannot add Virtual folders to a visual studio project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2019 and I haven't used it for a while. I want to make an empty ASP website that uses VB and allows for virtual folders. which ever project option I choose, once loaded when I right click on the website and click add the option is not there.

If I load up an old project and do the same the option is there.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Gareth

Comment: I don't think you could ever add a "virtual" folder to VS. This is setup on IIS, and not in VS. What you can do is create a folder in your project and THEN property sheet exclude the folder from the project. So this joe blow folder can exist and your code will see that folder on your local machine. When you publish to production, that virtual folder with the same name will exist. But as such, in VS you can't create a virtual folder, but for testing you can certainly have a folder in the project that exists - and assume after a publish that such a folder path will also exist.

Comment: Perhaps older versions did allow this option - but you can get the same effect by doing above.

Comment: what i have is 2 folders on my local drive, that contain common images / logo's etc. whenever i create a project i include these 2 folders as virtual directories so i can use the images if i need to. that way if i need to change the logo i just change the file in the folder on the local drive and it will change in each project automatically. when i publish the projects to our web server i add the same virtual directories in IIS and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me well - you should create a virtual folder in IIS/IIS Express and not in visual studio.

You could script the creation of virtual directories in PowerShell, and run the script when required:

`Remove-WebVirtualDirectory -Site "Default Web Site" -Application "test" -Name "images"`

`New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site "Default Web Site" -Name images -PhysicalPath c:\inetpub\myapp\images`